# Change font size in the same textview

Tags: android, textview, font-size, settext

Is it possible change size of temperature?

```
remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.battery, Color.WHITE);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, String.valueOf((int)batteryLevel + "%" + "|" + temperatura + "°C"));
```

Batterylevel and temperature are in the same textview. I want change size only of temperature. Actually is 50dp. I want 20dp.Hopw can i do it?

Comment: Have you check the [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html)? For more practical example, check the [Chris Umbel's blog post](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring) about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the size using HTML code, but I don't think it is possible to specify detailed sizes in dp with it.

In your case I would use the tag `<small>` for the temperature:

```
remoteViews.setTextColor(R.id.battery, Color.WHITE);
String styledText = String.valueOf((int)batteryLevel) + "%" + "|" + "<small>" + temperatura + "°C</small>";
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.battery, Html.fromHtml(styledText));
```

The list of supported tags is described here:
http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/

Comment: So you don't think its possible specify for example the pixels?

Comment: For now I did not find a way to do it, I'd like to know also :-)